# Replacing a node in graph with custom op having variable dependency in tensorflow

Tags: python, graph, tensorflow, custom-operator

I am trying to replace the computation done in the graph with a custom op that does the same.

Lets say the graph has a constant `A` and weight variable `W`, I create the custom op to take these two inputs and do the entire computation (except the last step of weight update):

```
custom_op_tensor = custom_module.custom_op([A,W])
g_def = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()
input_map = { tensor.name : custom_op_tensor }
train_op, = tf.import_graph_def(g_def, input_map=input_map, return_elements=[train_op])
```

After the import graph def, there are two `W`'s, one from the original graph def and one in the imported graph. When we run the train op, the custom op ends up reading the old `W` and the new `W` is updated. As a result, the gradient descent ends up failing to do the right thing.

The problem is instantiation of custom_op requires the input weight tensor `W`. The new `W` is known only after the import. And, import requires the custom op.
How does one get around this problem ?

Comment: You are asking how to replace an op in the graph with another op. Until recently graphs were append-only and it was not possible to do this. However, recently there's been a graph editor library added, perhaps there's some function there that can help -- https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/contrib.graph_editor.html#library-overview

Answer (score 0):

Could you precise which version of Tensorflow you use : r0.08, r0.09, r0.10, r0.11 ?

That is impossible to change an op in the graph with another op. 
But If you may access W, you can still make a backup copy of W (using deepcopy() [from copy module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) ) before running the train op which update it ?

Regards